# curl nginx as proxy server with "-i" works but with "-I" 404

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, node.js, curl

i'm trying to make nginx as proxy_server to nodejs app on port 3000 for testing purpose with compression,
when doing this:

```
curl -I -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' http://localhost/json
```

i go this:

[image: curl -I gives a 404 error]

and when curl it with -i with body shown

```
curl -i -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' http://localhost/json
```

i got this:

[image: with 200 status]

in nginx.conf file:

```
location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
}
```

in node app.js

```
//..
app.get('/json',(req,res)=>{
    res.json({Hello:'JSON'})
});
```

and again this seems weird when send some text for testing gzip

```
app.get('/', (req,res)=>{
    res.end('lorem ipsum ........ 100(lorem ipsum long text) ');
});
```

the content not reduced but when i add explicitly content-type the content size got compressed.

```
app.get('/', (req,res)=>{
    res.setHeader('Content-type','text/html');
    res.end('lorem ipsum ........ 100(lorem ipsum long text) ');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-I` makes a HEAD request while `-i` makes a GET request.

Your app most probably only answers GET requests.

Comment: Thanks, i didn't knew that there was a HEAD request, just printed out the req.method, i thought it ll just print out the response header by using -i( like not full response only header) so while i was doing .get() it sais 404 since there was no handler for HEAD request.